# Need to test that max number of files user can ftp on server using jmeter.

Tags: jmeter, sftp, performance-testing, load-testing

The application users will place some amount of file on server and then after a fixed interval of time a job will pick those files from server, read the data and put that data in db.

I need to do a load test on it that. basically need to determine that if users put lots of file (say 10000 files and size become 10-15 gb) then our application will able to the job or not.

I am thinking to test it using jmeter. please suggest what approach should i follow and is there any other elegant way instead of jmeter to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [FTP protocol specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/) you can transfer only one file at a time using one connection so theoretically you can end up with a batch file assuming usage of [ftp client utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687787(v=ws.11).aspx) which is included into major operating systems.

If you need to stress your FTP server you can simulate multiple file uploads with multiple virtual users using JMeter's [FTP Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request), the configuration is trivial, all you need is to provide host, port, credentials, source and destination file. See [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) for details.

Comment: Thanks.I want to determine the performance of the task done by the 'job' mentioned in ques. I have a utility which create lots of required files and then place them on the server. NOW the **job** which runs after every 5 mins pick file >> decrypt them >> read data >> place it in DB. I want to test if I place lots of files on server and this job runs then then will this job runs as expected or not. **I am thinking to ask dev people to log the time duration for which this job run and how many files it processed. I don't know if this is good and complete solution or not. please suggest**

Comment: Hi, Please someone help me on this